# The application crashes when I add intent or any view to savecallback method. Why?

Tags: android

when ever i try to add an intent inside `savecallback()` method the application crashes.

I added the intent outside the oncreatedialog and then called the method inside `savecallback()` but didnt work.

```
public class Dialogfragment extends DialogFragment {
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater

        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.make_group, null);
        final EditText n = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username));
        final EditText k = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password));

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(view)

        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton("create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ParseObject i = new ParseObject("username");
                i.put("username", n.getText().toString());
                i.put("password", k.getText().toString());
                i.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    ***public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Intent o = new Intent(getActivity(),activity.class);
                            startActivity(o);
                        }*** else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

> 01-20 01:35:03.905 24350-24350/com.example.android.uni1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                 at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:75)
>                                                                                 at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:4150)
>                                                                                 at com.example.android.uni1.Dialogfragment$2$1.done(Dialogfragment.java:56)
>                                                                                 at com.example.android.uni1.Dialogfragment$2$1.done(Dialogfragment.java:52)
>                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$1.done(ParseTaskUtils.java:74)
>                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$1.done(ParseTaskUtils.java:71)
>                                                                                 at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

this is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.game ">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--
         ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to   your project for
         App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".userlist"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_userlist"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".userlist"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.game.userlist" />
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

this is the activity

```
public class activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity);

}
```

}

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Replace these lines: Intent o = new Intent(getActivity(),activity.class);
                                           getActivity().startActivity(o);

Comment: it is still crashing

Comment: crash is same as it is or different one? Post your activity & manifest file here.

Comment: same crash same error

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Post your activity & manifest file here help u in better way

Comment: i posted the manifest file the activity is empty

Comment: which line numbers 52 and 56 in Dialogfragment.java?

Comment: wat do u mean by  
which line numbers 52 and 56 in Dialogfragment.java?

Answer (score 0):

Update AndroidManifest file as   **android:name="activity"** to  **android:name=".activity"**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".userlist"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.game.userlist" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: still not working the dot was there before i removed it somehow when pasting here

Comment: other things are ok. now in your logcat it shows error at line number  numbers 52 and 56 in Dialogfragment.java .So I want to ask you which are those lines because we don't have full class from package name import so we asking about line number.